# ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

```
data = (identic, username, profile, name, location, salary, work_mode, stack, experience, resume, coment, hashtag, date,)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Messages VALUES ("?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?");', (data,))
```

Выдаёт ошибку про отсутствие привязок:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
```

Изменение `data` с кортежа на список не помогло.

Если не передавать `identic`, то пишет, что не хватает одного значения (12 из 13).

`identic` в БД настроен на автоинкремент.

Comment: Не нужно заворачивать все знаки вопроса в кавычки, и `(data,)` надо заменить на `*data`

Comment: спасибо, это частично помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, surname) VALUES (''?, ?, ?)', (user_id, name, surname))
```

Попробуйте сделать запрос в данном виде, где вместо последних данных будет ваша переменная `data` без запятой в конце.

Вместо этого

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, surname)
```

запишите свои переменные, чтобы данные были заполнены правильно.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло